# "living water" association with Feast of Tabernacles

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-john

Is there authoritative support for the claim that John intends to portray Jesus as a replacement for the Feast of Tabernacles? I am interested in articles that develop this interpretation of the Woman at the Well story (John 4:5-42).

Comment: You might find this video interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ege-v7eheyo.

Comment: Grazia a lei, Sola Gratia. I'm developing a presentation for our parish RCIA catechumens, a meditation on the First Scrutiny readings. The video is very helpful.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!